# Laravel can't grab inputs from form to send out email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been trying to get my email to send from a POST on a form. I'm using Laravel and it's getting an error that it `emp_1_start is not defined`. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? I have used the same method to send another form.

> ErrorException in 34923b604b75ce6af5608d80e0c0cfda line 15: 
> Undefined
>   variable: emp_1_start 
> (View:
>   /home/fujita/ef/resources/views/emails/submitApplication.blade.php)

### JS

```
function formSubmit(){
    $(".step a.btn.next, .submit").on('click', function(e){
        var id       = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            bar      = $('.bar'),
            messages = $('.messages'),
            html     = $('html'),
            // over     = $('.overlay'),
            form     = $(this).closest('form'),
            curStep  = $(this).closest('.step').attr('data-id'),
            data     = form.serializeArray(),
            route    = window.location.pathname;
        e.preventDefault();
        bar.removeClass('error');
        html.removeClass('m-active');
        messages.find('ul > li').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: route,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                var pass = data['pass'];
                if(!pass){
                    // TODO: Add icon to let user know there is an error
                    $.each(data.ivInputs, function(index, item){
                        $('.' + item).next('.bar').addClass('error');
                    });

                    $.each(data['message'], function(index, item){
                        $('.messages ul').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
                    });

                    html.addClass('m-active');
                } else {
                    if(id == 5){
                        $('.progress').addClass('remove');
                    }
                    $('.step, .dot').removeClass('current');
                    $('.dot[data-id=step' + (id - 1) + ']').addClass('success');
                    $('.step[data-id=step' + id + '], .dot[data-id=step' + id + ']').addClass('current');
                }
            }
        });
    });
 }
```

### PHP - MailContoller

```
public function submitApplication(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        $rules = [];
        switch ($input['formStep']) {
            case 'step1':
                $rules = [
                    'name'               => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/',
                    'email'              => 'required|email',
                    'phone'              => 'required|regex:/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
                    'age_above_18_yn'    => 'required',
                    // 'age_above_18_yes' => 'required'
                ];
                break;
            case 'step2':
                $rules = [
                    'emp_1_start'        => 'required',
                    'emp_1_end'          => 'required',
                    'emp_1_title'        => 'required',
                    'emp_1_salary'       => 'required',
                    'emp_1_sup_name'     => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/',
                    'emp_1_sup_phone'    => 'required|regex:/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
                    'emp_1_duties'       => 'required',
                    'emp_2_start'        => 'required',
                    'emp_2_end'          => 'required',
                    'emp_2_title'        => 'required',
                    'emp_2_salary'       => 'required',
                    'emp_2_sup_name'     => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/',
                    'emp_2_sup_phone'    => 'required|regex:/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
                    'emp_2_duties'       => 'required',
                    'emp_3_start'        => 'required',
                    'emp_3_end'          => 'required',
                    'emp_3_title'        => 'required',
                    'emp_3_salary'       => 'required',
                    'emp_3_sup_name'     => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/',
                    'emp_3_sup_phone'    => 'required|regex:/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
                    'emp_3_duties'       => 'required'
                ];
                break;
            case 'step3':
                $rules = [
                    'ref_1_name'         => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/',
                    'ref_1_phone'        => 'required|regex:/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
                    'ref_1_relationship' => 'required',
                    'ref_2_name'         => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/',
                    'ref_2_phone'        => 'required|regex:/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
                    'ref_2_relationship' => 'required',
                    'ref_3_name'         => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/',
                    'ref_3_phone'        => 'required|regex:/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
                    'ref_3_relationship' => 'required'
                ];
                break;
            case 'step4':
                $rules = [
                    'availability'       => 'required',
                    'commitments'        => 'required',
                    'hear_about_us'      => 'required',
                    // 'comments'           => 'required'
                ];
                break;
            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }

        $messages = [
            'name.required'               => 'The Name Field is Required',
            'email.required'              => 'The Email Field is Required',
            'phone.required'              => 'The Phone Field is Required',
            'age_above_18_yn.required'    => 'The Are You Above 18 Field is Required',
            // 'age_above_18_yes.required'   => 'The Optional',
            'emp_1_start.required'        => 'Employer 1 Start Date Field is Required',
            'emp_1_end.required'          => 'Employer 1 End Date Field is Required',
            'emp_1_title.required'        => 'Employer 1 End Date Field is Required',
            'emp_1_salary.required'       => 'Employer 1 Salary Field is Required',
            'emp_1_sup_name.required'     => 'Employer 1 Supervisor Name Field is Required',
            'emp_1_sup_phone.required'    => 'The Employer 1 Supervisor Phone Number Field is Required',
            'emp_1_duties.required'       => 'Employer 1 List of Duties Field is Required',
            'emp_2_start.required'        => 'Employer 2 Start Date Field is Required',
            'emp_2_end.required'          => 'Employer 2 End Date Field is Required',
            'emp_2_title.required'        => 'Employer 2 End Date Field is Required',
            'emp_2_salary.required'       => 'Employer 2 Salary Field is Required',
            'emp_2_sup_name.required'     => 'Employer 2 Supervisor Name Field is Required',
            'emp_2_sup_phone.required'    => 'The Employer 2 Supervisor Phone Number Field is Required',
            'emp_2_duties.required'       => 'Employer 2 List of Duties Field is Required',
            'emp_3_start.required'        => 'Employer 3 Start Date Field is Required',
            'emp_3_end.required'          => 'Employer 3 End Date Field is Required',
            'emp_3_title.required'        => 'Employer 3 End Date Field is Required',
            'emp_3_salary.required'       => 'Employer 3 Salary Field is Required',
            'emp_3_sup_name.required'     => 'Employer 3 Supervisor Name Field is Required',
            'emp_3_sup_phone.required'    => 'The Employer 3 Supervisor Phone Number Field is Required',
            'emp_3_duties.required'       => 'Employer 3 List of Duties Field is Required',
            'ref_1_name.required'         => 'The Reference 1 Name Field is Required',
            'ref_1_phone.required'        => 'The Reference 1 Phone Number Field is Required',
            'ref_1_relationship.required' => 'The Reference 1 Relationship Field is Required',
            'ref_1_name.required'         => 'The Reference 2 Name Field is Required',
            'ref_1_phone.required'        => 'The Reference 2 Phone Number Field is Required',
            'ref_1_relationship.required' => 'The Reference 2 Relationship Field is Required',
            'ref_3_name.required'         => 'The Reference 3 Name Field is Required',
            'ref_3_phone.required'        => 'The Reference 3 Phone Number Field is Required',
            'ref_3_relationship.required' => 'The Reference 3 Relationship Field is Required',
            'availability.required'       => 'The Your Availability Field is Required',
            'commitments.required'        => 'The Your Prior Commitments Field is Required',
            'hear_about_us.required'      => 'The How Did You Hear About Us Field is Required',
            'comments.required'           => 'The Comments Field is Required'
        ];
        // dd($input);
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $ivInputs = [];
            foreach($validator->invalid() as $key => $value){
                $ivInputs[] = $key;
            }
            return json_encode(array("pass" => false, "message" => $validator->messages()->all(), 'ivInputs' => $ivInputs));
        }
        else {
            Mail::send('emails.submitApplication', $input, function($message) use ($input) {
                $message->from("noreply@test.com", "New Employment Application");
                $message->to('test@test.com')->subject('New Employment Application');
            });
            return json_encode(array("pass" => true, "message" => "You Have a New Employment Application"));
        }
    }
```

### Email From POST

```
<h4>You Have a New Application from {{$name}}</h4>

<hr>
<h3>General Contact Information</h3>
<hr>
<p>Name: {{$name}}</p>
<p>Email: {{$email}}</p>
<p>Phone Number: {{$phone}}</p>
{{-- <p>Comments: {{$comments}}</p> --}}
<hr>
<h3>Employment History</h3>
<hr>

<p>Employer 1 Start Date: {{$emp_1_start}}</p>
<p>Employer 1 End Date: {{$emp_1_end}}</p>
<p>Employer 1 Title: {{$emp_1_title}}</p>
<p>Employer 1 Salary: {{$emp_1_salary}}</p>
<p>Employer 1 Supervisor Name: {{$emp_1_sup_name}}</p>
<p>Employer 1 Supervisor Phone: {{$emp_1_sup_phone}}</p>
<p>Employer 1 Supervisor Duties: {{$emp_1_duties}}</p>
<hr>
<p>Employer 2 Start Date: {{$emp_2_start}}</p>
<p>Employer 2 End Date: {{$emp_2_end}}</p>
<p>Employer 2 Title: {{$emp_2_title}}</p>
<p>Employer 2 Salary: {{$emp_2_salary}}</p>
<p>Employer 2 Supervisor Name: {{$emp_2_sup_name}}</p>
<p>Employer 2 Supervisor Phone: {{$emp_2_sup_phone}}</p>
<p>Employer 2 Supervisor Duties: {{$emp_2_duties}}</p>
<hr>
<p>Employer 3 Start Date: {{$emp_3_start}}</p>
<p>Employer 3 End Date: {{$emp_3_end}}</p>
<p>Employer 3 Title: {{$emp_3_title}}</p>
<p>Employer 3 Salary: {{$emp_3_salary}}</p>
<p>Employer 3 Supervisor Name: {{$emp_3_sup_name}}</p>
<p>Employer 3 Supervisor Phone: {{$emp_3_sup_phone}}</p>
<p>Employer 3 Supervisor Duties: {{$emp_3_duties}}</p>

<hr>
<h3>References</h3>
<hr>
<p>Reference 1 Name: {{$ref_1_name}}</p>
<p>Reference 1 Phone Number: {{$ref_1_phone}}</p>
<p>Reference 1 Relationship: {{$ref_1_relationship}}</p>
<hr>
<p>Reference 2 Name: {{$ref_2_name}}</p>
<p>Reference 2 Phone Number: {{$ref_2_phone}}</p>
<p>Reference 2 Relationship: {{$ref_2_relationship}}</p>
<hr>
<p>Reference 3 Name: {{$ref_3_name}}</p>
<p>Reference 3 Phone Number: {{$ref_3_phone}}</p>
<p>Reference 3 Relationship: {{$ref_3_relationship}}</p>

<hr>
<h3>Other Information</h3>
<hr>
<p>Availability: {{$availability}}</p>
<p>Commitments: {{$commitments}}</p>
<p>How Did You Hear About Us?: {{$hear_about_us}}</p>
<p>Comments: {{$comments}}</p>
```

Comment: If `emp_1_start` makes the problem then remove all other unecessary fields from your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `<p>Employer 1 Start Date: {{$input['emp_1_start']}}</p>` to `<p>Employer 1 Start Date: {{$emp_1_start}}</p>`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change that back from trying things. I fixed it now. That still doesn't fix the error though. Its throws the error I put above. I have tried $input['emp_1_start'] as you saw before and tried var dumping $input. I have tried multiple things and its still a no go :(

Comment: You must be sure that `$input['formStep']` is `'step2'` as only then you have guarantee that `$emp_1_start` is present.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Thank you soooo much for your help. I just realized that as I went to check my messages here :/.